# Rounding off the value to a decimal to 2 in Oracle for a query

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, rounding

Rounding off the query's value to a decimal to 2 in Oracle

Doubt : select (1200 + 1245 + 1234) / 12 from dual;
 Gives result as 306.583333333333

Expected Result as 306.58

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

use round

```
select round( (1200 + 1245 + 1234) / 12 ,2)from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Resolved my issue :) Thanks again!